# How to create report from SSIS package when its executed?

Tags: sql, ssis

I have an SSIS package that loads data in a table. How do I create a report from that table every time the package would run?

NOTE : I asked somebody about this issue and this is what he told me:

Create a variable called SSISReport and update that variable in package configuration so every time you have the records in that table, the report will be generated from SSISLogs.

Comment: Are you talking about a report that shows statistics of the ETL run (like time it took to load the table, rows inserted, etc) or a report showing some stuff using the data that you just inserted?

Comment: In addition to Faiz's comment about content above, what format do you want the report in?  CSV file?  Excel spreadsheet?  PDF?  Text email?  SMS?  Tweet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a logs table in my database and a sp_ that inserts rows into it.  When the package starts, I delete all the existing records in the log table.  Before each action in the package, I call my sp with a comment describing what I'm about to do in the package.  After the last package action, I call the sp again saying it's done.

The log table has a timestamp so I can see the last time the package ran successfully and how long each step took.

There are other ways to do logging in SSIS, but I don't have admin access anywhere, so I created my own table.

HTH